# Train and Test Data Split for a Tweet Classification Task

Tags: python, classification, pandas, text-classification

I am trying to train a few Machine Learning (ML) algorithms such as SVM, NB and Random Forest to do binary classification on disaster tweets. During this project, I want to train ML algorithms for a combined disaster dataset. However, I want to apply it to individual disasters separately (e.g, train on multiple disasters, apply to earthquake; train on multiple disasters, apply to flood). I have the combined dataset in one `pandas` `DataFrame` and individual disasters in separate `DataFrames`.
In this case, how should I split my train and test datasets? At the moment, I split my combined dataset and apply ML algorithms.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(all_disaster['cleaned'], all_disaster['target'], test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

But, I feel that is not the proper way, as I want to apply it into individual disasters.

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(all_disaster['cleaned'],specific_disaster['target'], test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Like this, you train your model on all the disasters data, and you test it on a specific disaster.

Comment: Many thanks. But then how sklearn can split as train and test. Train and test data sets are of different sizes.

Comment: you need to have the same number of features, otherwise, it won't be logical to do so.